# Getting the caller URL in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to determine the URL of the request caller in a Rails controller.

I tried using `request.env['HTTP_REFERER']` but it's sometimes null. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure it's a bug? I believe, referer may be null if a user opens a page from bookmarks or by typing it's address.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This answer covers the particulars of HTTP_REFERER in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3104799/9465)

Answer (score 0):

You're just going to have to deal with the fact that sometimes there will be no requesting URL. as a commenter said, if a user types the URL in or if it's a bookmark, the referrer field will be empty. And those are just legitimate, everyday cases.

Don't depend on that field being there.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. Is there any other way I can know the caller url, I need to reject requests if coming from certain urls is that possible in Rails?

Comment: If you're looking to block URLs, why don't you block their IP addresses instead? The IP address is always available. This is also not a completely reliable method, since the offending URL can change its IP, but it's better than blocking URLs themselves.

Comment: I can use the ip address but I'm trying to solve a simple problem where I need to accept requests only if they come from a certain URL. I used the following to get the host address: host = request.env['REMOTE_HOST']
    if host.blank?
      host = Resolv.new.getname( request.env['REMOTE_ADDR'])
    end I couldn't find out whether the value of request.env['REMOTE_ADDR'] can be blank or it has to be set