# rails request.env["HTTP_REFERER"] giving nil on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, http-headers, http-referer

I have created a ruby on rails application. I am having below scenario

In localhost for getting referrer link i'm using `request.env["HTTP_REFERER"]` it's working perfectly not giving null.

I have uploaded the code in heroku , but `request.env["HTTP_REFERER"]` is giving `nil` , i have checked in heroku logs.

Please provide a suggestion why it's giving `nil` ? is there any way to get referrer link other than `request.env["HTTP_REFERER"]` ?

Comment: Some question was in SF. [Please, see this question][1]

This help for you?

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3104711/ruby-on-rails-request-envhttp-referer-returns-nil

Comment: I can confirm the behavior of Heroku. However, we have a setup with Play Framework 2.1 / Scala. On localhost it works as designed. Any updates on this question from your side? Did you find a solution by now?

Comment: I think more details about the referer page and the context of the `request.env["HTTP_REFERER"] would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

`request.env["HTTP_REFERER"]` giving `nil` is acceptable when directly navigating to a page, I suggest to use `link_to :back` instead or specify where it should go back (`link_to root_path`).