# Rails HTTP_REFERER is empty after paypal redirection.

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am building a rails paypal integration, I am ussing the sandbox 
and after the purchace I am redirecting the user on a "Your transaction has been completed"
page. 
I want to prevent though users to directly access the page.

So I am trying to trace HTTP_REFERER but is not been set

```
request.env.has_key?('HTTP_REFERER')

<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3104711/ruby-on-rails-request-envhttp-referer-returns-nil/3104799#3104799>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest doing it another way. Trusting the referrer is not a very secure way to prevent users from accessing pages as it can be easily manipulated by the user and it is unreliable.

Typically, if you're re-directing from HTTPS to HTTP, it will be empty as I suspect this is the case.

I would use either sessions or the PayPal token to prevent users from accessing the page. If an order session number is set, and payment is completed through PayPal (PayPal will send you details back that the payment is a success, token etc.), then display the payment completion page.

Comment: How does paypal sending back this info ?

Comment: Is this a paypal express transaction?

Comment: No It's the standard payment proccess.