# Does "request.referer == nil" always mean direct traffic?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, httprequest, http-referer

When `request.referer` doesn't return anything, does that always mean that the visitor didn't do the request through a link - i.e. she somehow manually entered the requested page's address?

Or are there other cases where `request.referer` returns `nil` (granted that the request is successful)?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/3104799/532252

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Generally speaking, the referrer - like all other HTTP headers - is user submitted data. User submitted data should not be trusted.

Off the top of my head I can think of these scenarios, where the referrer wouldn't be set without the user having manually entered the URL.

- Clicking a link in an email client.
- Using privacy software that removes referrers.
- Bots/spiders might not set this header.
- [Following a link from a HTTPS site to a HTTP site](http://makandracards.com/makandra/15931-browsers-will-not-send-a-referrer-when-linking-from-https-to-http).

There might well be other cases (fx I am not sure how browsers handle referrers when opening links in new windows).

And then there are the cases where the referrer is set, but no user has entered the address; notably bots - especially the referrer-spamming ones.

Answer (score -2):

I have not verified that but it's always safe not to check `nil` for blank value but to use `blank?`

```
request.referrer.blank?
```

This ensure the case when it's nil or blank string.